# angular js checkbox and select dynamic binding to give total price

Tags: angularjs, select, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I have a working code that gives the sum of the total item in a json file after ticking one or all of the checkboxes

Here is my controller

```
$scope.testFood = [{ name: item1, price: 400 }, { name: item2, price: 800 }, { name: item3, price: 1000 }];
$scope.selectedItems = [];
        $scope.value = function (isSelected, item) {
        if (isSelected == true) {
            $scope.selectedItems.push(item);
        } else {
            // console.log(item.name);
            angular.forEach($scope.selectedItems, function (itemRmv, $index) {
                if (itemRmv.itemid == item.itemid) {
                    $scope.selectedItems.splice($index, 1);
                }
            })
        }
        console.log($scope.selectedItems);
    }
```

The filter:

```
.filter('getprice', function () {
    return function (value, property) {
        var total = 0;
        angular.forEach(value, function (val, index) {
            total = total + Number(val.price)
        });
        return total.toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

The html template:

```
<ul class="list" ng-repeat ="item in testFood">

  <li class="item item-checkbox">
     <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-change="value(item.isSelected,item)">
     </label>
     {{item.package_name}}  &nbsp; &nbsp; <p>N {{item.price}}</p>
  </li> X
 <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="number" value="0"  min="0" step="1">
  </label>
</ul>
```

Calling `{{selectedItems | getprice}}` gives the total price.
I want the quantity for each product to be calculated along side the total price, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How you you want to show the quantities? you already have the count in the number input. BTW There are some errors in your code. eg. you define `items` on $scope and iterate over `testFood` in template.

Comment: the quantity will be showin in the input box <input type="number" value="0"  min="0" step="1"> with dynamically binded ngModel for each checkboxes